# Reserved words interferece with identifiers in parser combinators

Tags: parsing, keyword, identifier, parser-combinators, reserved-words

I have the following simple grammar

```
primary ::= name | literal
factor ::= primary| "not" primary
```

which I [try to parse with the help of scala combinators](http://scastie.org/13898)

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

object ExprWithReservedWords extends App with JavaTokenParsers {
  def test(title: String, primary: Parser[_]) {
    println(title + " " + parseAll(primary | "not" ~ primary, "not 1 "))
  }

  test("wholeNumber", wholeNumber) // parsed: (not~1)
  test("wholeNumber | ident", wholeNumber | ident) // failure: string matching regex `\z' expected but `1' found
}
```

If only numbers are allowed in the primary, `wholeNumber` then everything is fine. However, if identifiers are permitted, `primary = wholeNumber | ident` then parsing fails with input "not 1", which should be a single-factor term. Obviously, it is because parser decides that "not" is an identifier rather than keyword prefix for a primary. How do you resolve the conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to try the reserved word-prefixed alternatives first, note that `primary | "not" primary` was changed to `"not" primary | primary`

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

object ExprWithReservedWords extends App with JavaTokenParsers {
  def test(title: String, primary: Parser[_]) {
    println(title + " " + parseAll("not" ~ primary | primary, "not 1 "))
  }

  test("wholeNumber", wholeNumber)
  test("wholeNumber | ident", wholeNumber | ident)
}
```

[This works](http://scastie.org/13909) but I am still not sure that this is a proper practice.

Update. I see in *Compilers, Principles, Techniques, & Tools* that *reserved* stands for banned identifiers, which makes languages much easier when keywords are reserved. So, `ident` must filter the keywords out.